# PhP/MySQL - how to add parameters like ?q=blabla to url

Tags: php, mysql, url

I know this question must be very, very basic since even beginners are asking more advanced questions, but I can't find the answer.. I have searched for hours on this, so please condone my ignorance.

**What I have**: localhost:8888/site/document.php

It loads some data from my MySQL database on this page, such as q = office.

**What I want**: localhost:8888/site/document.php?q=office

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those are [`GET`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php) requests.

Comment: Just put ?q=office on the end. Unclear what issue you're having. Can you explain better?

Comment: Based on your question one can just say *"On your browser's address bar, type localhost:8888/site/document.php?q=office"* .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you really want to do, but it could be as simple as setting a redirection after you get the sql data.

```
header('Location: document.php?q=office');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set the session variable using 
GET method 
">Office

$_SESSION["b"] = "Office";
$office = $_SESSION["b"];

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 localhost:8888/site/document.php?q=office
```

and get that value by using $_GET;

```
<?php

echo $_GET['q'];//outputs:office.
?>
```

or if you need to redirect to page use

```
header("Location: document.php?q=office"); // NOte : dont keep any echo before this statement.
```

Answer (score 0):

You must read about php GET/POST
There are two ways the browser client can send information to the web server.

**The GET Method**

Before the browser sends the information, it encodes it using a scheme called URL encoding. In this scheme, name/value pairs are joined with equal signs and different pairs are separated by the ampersand.

name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3

Spaces are removed and replaced with the + character and any other nonalphanumeric characters are replaced with a hexadecimal values. After the information is encoded it is sent to the server.
The GET Method

The GET method sends the encoded user information appended to the page request. The page and the encoded information are separated by the ? character.

http://www.test.com/index.htm?name1=value1&name2=value2

```
<?php
   if( $_GET["name"] || $_GET["age"] ) {
      echo "Welcome ". $_GET['name']. "<br />";
      echo "You are ". $_GET['age']. " years old.";

      exit();
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "GET">
         Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" />
         Age: <input type = "text" name = "age" />
         <input type = "submit" />
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

For more please read
    http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Source:
    http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to [GET params](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

try open page localhost:8888/site/document.php?q=123

and in php put thi code

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['q'];

    print_r($_GET);
```